# Convert ADC value to real voltage

Tags: microcontroller, adc, math

I want to measure the input voltage to my circuit. The input voltage is supposed to be anything between 7 to 35 Volts.

I have a micro-controller with 12bit ADC. I am using a simple voltage divider to connect a fraction of input voltage to the ADC pin.

The voltage divider is simply a `R1 = 82k` on top and `R2 = 5.6k` resistor on bottom.

According to my calculation, at 35V I should get (never mind the tolerance):

```
V_IN = (V_SUPPLY * R2) / (R1 + R2) = (V_SUPPLY * 5k6) / (82k + 5k6) = 2.24
```

And the same calculation at 7 Volts I should get 0.4V into the ADC pin.

Now the question is, how to convert the raw value of the ADC to a voltage?

If I supply my circuit with 12V and if I did the programming of ADC correct, I am reading the raw value of around `840` out of my ADC.

The ADC reference voltage of controller is 3.3 Volts.

Comment: What is the ADC reference voltage?

Comment: @LongPham it is 3.3 volts

Comment: Well, use the formula: V = reading * Vref / (2^n - 1). Since the ADC voltage is proportional with the input voltage, you can calculate it easily.

Comment: Just a note:
 
If you are doing fast conversions the SAR sampling current (if unbuffered) will reduce your measured voltage because of that 82K resistor- check your RC time constants to make sure you are OK on accuracy.

Comment: A quick and dirty way is to add a capacitor in parallel with R2, however to do accurate continuous conversions you will either have to have an op-amp or compensate for the drop in voltage by adding in the SAR load on your R1/R2 voltage divider.  The scaling equation has already been done by Spehro below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V = (R/4096)*Vref*(82K + 5.6K)/5.6K

Which gives me about 10.6V, which I suspect is too far off from 12.0V to be explained by even 5% resistor tolerances and a few percent Vref tolerance.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I have the wrong resistors in place. now it works fine :)