# How to convert raw ADC value into voltage in volts in software?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, voltage-measurement, c++

Let's say I have a microcontroller with an ADC and my goal is to measure instantaneous values of the line to line voltage of the three phase grid 400 V/50 Hz.

I have a voltage [instrument transformer](https://datasheet.octopart.com/BV-202-0168-HAHN-datasheet-124687159.pdf) with the following nameplate data: 400V/6V. Secondary winding of that transformer is connected directly to the 16 bit ADC which has bipolar channels +/-10V.

As far as the conversion from the raw data read from the ADC into the voltage in volts I have following idea how to do that in C++ software:

```cpp
    uint16_t raw_value
    float voltage
    
    if (raw_value & 0x8000) {
          // negative number in 2's complement
          voltage = (static_cast<float>(raw_value) - 65536) / 32768 * 666.66;
    } else {
          // positive number in 2's complement
          voltage = static_cast<float>(raw_value) / 32768 * 666.66;
    }
```

As far as the value 666.66 it is a channel norm i.e. voltage at the primary side of the transformer corresponding to the full scale value of the ADC i.e. 10V. I have calculated this value based on following \$6\,V \sim 400\,V\$ i.e. \$10\,V \sim 10\cdot\frac{400}{6} = 666.66\,V\$. Basically this value specifies the maximum measurable amplitude (with given transformer and adc) of the line to line voltage.

Can someone tell me whether my approach to converting raw ADC data into voltage in volts is correct (namely in respect to the channel norm)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert ADC value to real voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402411/convert-adc-value-to-real-voltage)

Comment: Have you taken into account RMS and peak values? AC voltage is usually notes as RMS, however your ADC will read the peak. A square root of two will do.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson thank you for your reaction. I have also found this question but it doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: @Kartman thank you for your reaction. As far as I understand your comment you think that the channel norm (in my case 666.66V) shall be multiplied by \$\sqrt{2}\$?

Comment: Do you want the voltage to read as peak or RMS? How are you sampling the data?
If you feed in 400Vrms, the adc and your scaling will read 400 * 1.4142 Volts. So you might want to multiply by 1/square root of 2

Comment: It depends how you detect and sample the data ,Pk, avg or thermal RMS

Comment: @Kartman I would like to read the instantaneous values of the sine wave i.e. also the peak value.

Comment: Hello, professor: most ADC,s with bipolar inputs output a number in signed 2’s complement form.   A 16 bit processor will just use this number as a positive and negative integer between -(2^15+1) and 2^15. So, there is no need to detect signs. You should declare the input as an int16_t and then scale it how you wish, using normal arithmetic.

Comment: Hello, user69795: thank you for your idea. Please can you tell me what do you think about the value of the channel norm?